# Code works outside of a function but not inside

Tags: r, function

Sorry for making this non-reproducible. This code basically recodes various columns according to quartiles into new variables `_REC`, and adds them to a matrix.

These are the names of the variables I need.

```
admin<-c("D5_1_Num_contractes_Ajuntaments_abans_estat_alarma","D5_2_Num_contractes_Consells_Comarcals_abans_estat_alarma","D5_3_Num_contractes_Generalitat_abans_estat_alarma","D5_4_Num_contractes_Altres_AAPP_abans_estat_alarma")
```

And this is the code which works.

```
columnes<-admin

dades<-vector()
for(i in 1:length(columnes)){
  dades<-c(dades,m[,colnames(m)==columnes[i]])
}
quartils<-signif(quantile(dades,c(0.25,0.5,0.75),na.rm=TRUE),1)
for(i in 1:length(columnes)){
  m<-cbind(m,recod_quart(m[,colnames(m)==columnes[i]],quartils))
}
colnames(m)[(ncol(m)-length(columnes)+1):ncol(m)]<-paste0(columnes,"_REC")
```

And this the chunk of code which doesn't.

```
recod_columnes<-function(columnes){
  dades<-vector()
  for(i in 1:length(columnes)){
    dades<-c(dades,m[,colnames(m)==columnes[i]])
  }
  quartils<-signif(quantile(dades,c(0.25,0.5,0.75),na.rm=TRUE),1)
  for(i in 1:length(columnes)){
    m<-cbind(m,recod_quart(m[,colnames(m)==columnes[i]],quartils))
  }
  colnames(m)[(ncol(m)-length(columnes)+1):ncol(m)]<-paste0(columnes,"_REC")
}

recod_columnes(columnes=admin)
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work. What happens exactly? Do you get an error (what does it say?) or does the result just not make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I could not really find out the problem in your code because you did not tell what the function `recod_quart` does exactly (I also did not find an R-function of this name anywhere online). If you did not define this function, then that seems to be the problem.

Anyway, I do have an idea of what you want to achieve, but you have to tell whether this is what you want:

```
get.qs <- function(x) {
  qq <- quantile(x, c(0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1), na.rm=TRUE) #find the quartile "breaks" in x
  cut(x, breaks=qq, labels=FALSE, include.lowest=TRUE) #return quartiles as numbers 1-4
}

col.quartiles <- function(dades, columnes) {
  dades <- as.data.frame(dades) #data frames make indexing easyier
  dd <- matrix(nrow=nrow(dades), ncol=length(columnes)) #preallocate result matrix
  for( i in 1:length(columnes) ) dd[, i] <- get.qs(dades[ ,columnes[i]]) #use get.qs
  colnames(dd) <- paste0(columnes, "_REC") #make the new column names
  dd
}
```

I am sure there must be a more elegant method for the second function using some tools in the `dplyr` package but this solution uses base R only, which I personally prefer for functions that might be reused in the future.

I tested the function with the following reproducible example:

```
set.seed(101)
m <- cbind(A = runif(20, 1, 10),
           B = runif(20, 1, 10),
           C = runif(20, 1, 10),
           D = runif(20, 1, 10),
           E = runif(20, 1, 10)
           )

cc <- c("A", "D", "E")

col.quartiles(dades=m, columnes=cc)
```

Please note that I left out the `signif()` function because rounding the quantiles can result in errors for the lowest or highest values in a column. For instance if the lowest value is 0.99 then the 0-quantile is rounded to 1 and the original value 0.99 is *outside* the range defined by the rounded quantiles.